# SQL XML .Modify syntax

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to figure out what wrong with my XML update query. I don't have much experience working with XML in SQL but I thought this should work.

I want to update a value of the PATH value in XML.

Here's what I am currently trying:

```
DECLARE @PATH VARCHAR(500) = 'TEST'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SUBSCRIPTION', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #SUBSCRIPTION;

CREATE TABLE #SUBSCRIPTION (ExtensionSettings xml)

INSERT #SUBSCRIPTION
        ( ExtensionSettings )
SELECT '<ParameterValues><ParameterValue><Name>PATH</Name><Value>\\valinor\group\XFER</Value></ParameterValue><ParameterValue><Name>FILENAME</Name><Value>REPORT CARD TEST - SITE - YYYYMMDD</Value></ParameterValue><ParameterValue><Name>FILEEXTN</Name><Value>True</Value></ParameterValue><ParameterValue><Name>RENDER_FORMAT</Name><Value>PDF</Value></ParameterValue><ParameterValue><Name>WRITEMODE</Name><Value>Overwrite</Value></ParameterValue></ParameterValues>' 


SELECT LEN(CAST(ExtensionSettings AS varchar(8000))) DL_XML, CAST(ExtensionSettings AS varchar(8000)) EXT_XML
FROM #SUBSCRIPTION  

-- UPDATE ATTRIBUTE
UPDATE #SUBSCRIPTION
SET ExtensionSettings.modify('replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue/@Name[.="PATH"])[1] with sql:variable("@PATH")')

SELECT LEN(CAST(ExtensionSettings AS varchar(8000))) DL_XML, CAST(ExtensionSettings AS varchar(8000)) EXT_XML
FROM #SUBSCRIPTION
```

SQL Server says 1 row affected but nothing changes.

I need to update other columns too but **ass**u**me** once I get this working the others will work the same way.

Can you help me and point out what I am doing incorrectly? I am trying to automate some SSRS file share subscriptions but the only examples I find are for e-mail and they edit the XML data as text.

Below is the XML I'm working with in a readable format:

```
<ParameterValues>
    <ParameterValue>
        <Name>PATH</Name>
        <Value>\\valinor\group\XFER</Value>
    </ParameterValue>
    <ParameterValue>
        <Name>FILENAME</Name>
        <Value>REPORT CARD TEST - SITE - YYYYMMDD</Value>
    </ParameterValue>
    <ParameterValue>
        <Name>FILEEXTN</Name>
        <Value>True</Value>
    </ParameterValue>
    <ParameterValue>
        <Name>RENDER_FORMAT</Name>
        <Value>PDF</Value>
    </ParameterValue>
    <ParameterValue>
        <Name>WRITEMODE</Name>
        <Value>Overwrite</Value>
    </ParameterValue>
</ParameterValues>
```

Comment: I noticed a few things, ParameterValue is a repeated node.  Not sure how to update that.  Also if I change the UPDATE path to something fake `SET ExtensionSettings.modify('replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValueFAKEPATH/@Name[.="PATH"])[1] with sql:variable("@PATH")')` it will still say it updated 1 row so that might be a goose chase.

Comment: @sniperd - I see what you mean about it saying updated when it has a unused path. I did finally figure it out. The **ParameterValue[Name="PATH"]/** apparently filters by the ParameterValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours of trial and error, I have figured out the syntax to update the value of one element based on the value of another element in the same node^. I wasn't able to find a similar example.

```
-- UPDATE PATH ATTRIBUTE
UPDATE #SUBSCRIPTION 
SET ExtensionSettings.modify('replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name="PATH"]/Value/text())[1] with sql:variable("@PATH")')

-- UPDATE FILENAME ATTRIBUTE
UPDATE #SUBSCRIPTION 
SET ExtensionSettings.modify('replace value of (/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name="FILENAME"]/Value/text())[1] with sql:variable("@FILENAME")')
```

Before:

```
<ParameterValues>
<ParameterValue><Name>PATH</Name><Value>\\valinor\group\XFER</Value></ParameterValue>
<ParameterValue><Name>FILENAME</Name><Value>REPORT CARD TEST - YYYMMDD</Value></ParameterValue>
<ParameterValue><Name>FILEEXTN</Name><Value>True</Value></ParameterValue>
<ParameterValue><Name>RENDER_FORMAT</Name><Value>PDF</Value></ParameterValue>
<ParameterValue><Name>WRITEMODE</Name><Value>Overwrite</Value></ParameterValue>
</ParameterValues>
```

After:

```
<ParameterValues>
<ParameterValue><Name>PATH</Name><Value>\\valinor\group\XFER\TEST\Site1</Value></ParameterValue>
<ParameterValue><Name>FILENAME</Name><Value>0123456X - 20180615</Value></ParameterValue>
<ParameterValue><Name>FILEEXTN</Name><Value>True</Value></ParameterValue
<ParameterValue><Name>RENDER_FORMAT</Name><Value>PDF</Value></ParameterValue>
<ParameterValue><Name>WRITEMODE</Name><Value>Overwrite</Value></ParameterValue>
</ParameterValues>
```

Now if I could just figure out how to combine these into one statement. But close enough for now.

^Please feel free to correct any incorrect wording.